# The meaning of "there" in a sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> We do not always know what products are there on the market.
>  We do not always know what products are there available.

Are these two sentences grammatically correct and what does "there" in the sentences mean? Thanks a lot.
If I rewrite the sentence as "We do not always know what products are there avilable on the market",is it acceptable or grammatical? Thank you again.

Comment: A good friend is someone who is always there for you ;)

Comment: In such cases, 'there' is a superfluous word. The word is used just to emphasize with no 'additional information' served.

Comment: it is indicative of the 'existence' of something at(in) some location/point/reality. "We do not always know what products are there in the market." (What PRODUCTS [something] are in the MARKET[somewhere]) Remember that in Mathematics/Logic, resulting sets are explained with the use of the opening phrase, "There exist(s)..." (i.e., given set A and set B, **there exist(s)**...)

Answer (score 2):

IMO, in both these sentences, 'there' is used as an adverb of place.

However, the second sentence can be reworded like this:

> We do not always know what products are available ***there*** (OR ***on the market***).

The first sentence seems an extension to the above sentence, and in both these sentence 'there' shows location/point.

Answer (score 0):

I think they're not.
I would write them in the following way.

> We do not always know which products there are on the market.
>
> We do not always know which products are available.

Examples: 
"There are three products on the market." 
"Are there products on the market?" 
"Is there that product on the market?" 
"There is a product in the market."

Comment: Where is 'there' in the second sentence?

Comment: In the second sentence it is unnecessary: "we do not always know which products there are available" is redundant in my opinion.